# Deleting an object inside another object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First, I know that React is javascript, but that's not why I can do it anyway. And following the philosophy of "pure functions", I'm using filter to remove things.

The problem is this: I have a collection, where each one has a title and an array with other objects, and what I want to do is remove a specific object inside the array of the main object.

Example:

```
// the state is like this
const collections = [ 
{
    id: 3,
    title: 'Machine Learning repos',
    coll_type: 'r',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/collections/3/',
    repos: [
      {
        id: 68,
        name: 'tensorflow',
        owner: 'tensorflow',
        collection: 3
      },
      {
        id: 76,
        name: 'requests',
        owner: 'kennethreitz',
        collection: 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When I click on a button to delete, it calls this function, passing the id of the collection and the repo:

```
const handleRepoDelete = (collectionId, repoId) => {
    // get the collections state
    const _newCollections = [...collections];
    // get the collection by id
    const collection = _newCollections.filter(
        _collection => {
            return _collection.id === collectionId
        }
    )[0]

    // remove repo by id
    collection.repos.filter(
        repo => {
            // here is not works
            // is returning even when the ids are different
            return repo.id !== repoId
        }
    )

    // remove old collection with repo to delete
    _newCollections.filter(
        _collection => {
            // here alse is not works
            // is returning even when the ids are different, and the new and old collection
            return _collection.id !== collection.id
        }
    )
    // iterate in array with old collection deleted
    // and add new collection with repo deleted
    const newCollections = [..._newCollections, collection];
    setCollections(newCollections);
}
```

The problem is that I do not know the cleanest way to resolve this, and as you can see, the repository clicked is not being removed in the filter method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution.

```
const handleRepoDelete = (collectionId, repoId) => {
  // we will map each item of the collections array
  // will only change the collection with collectionId
  // meaning, if not, we will return the original collection
  const newCollections = collections.map(
    (collection) => {
      const {
        id, repos
      } = collection
      // if the id doesn't match, just return it
      if (id !== collectionId) {
        return collection
      }
      // otherwise here we return a new object
      // only changing repos prop of it
      // using spread syntax, we filter repos
      // at the end, we returned the collection
      // with the changes we want
      return {
        ...collection,
        repos: repos.filter( ({ id }) => id !== repoId )
      }
    }
  )
  setCollections(newCollections);
}
```

Comment: this works, you can read my comments in the code and explain how this works? https://pastebin.com/GwpQimXZ. I'm new in the JS/React. I have a maximum of 3 months of study (I started a long time ago, but I always stopped by hating JS and spent time rereading the things I already learned). If possible, send me some article that explains this well, I do not know what to look for.

Comment: I did not introduce anything new that doesn't exist in your code. Array.map, Array.filter and spread syntax (...). So, if you try harder, you can understand how my solution works. Being able to write this code yourself requires some practice of these methods. I would recommend practicing on hackerrank, for instance.

Comment: From what I understand, you are creating an object by getting all the fields in the collection, but you are applying the filter to the repos property.

Comment: Let me write some comments, np.

Comment: I think I get it. I've seen something like: {...< return old object properties>, <new properties to replace>}

Comment: And about the use of map. Should I use it when I want to change something inside it, and use filter on the objects / arrays that I want to change? I'll try hackerrank later, I've seen about but I gave up because it involved a lot of math in some exercises, and I do not remember anything I studied at school

Comment: Map when you want to update some items of an array, filter when you want to remove any item.

Comment: Both are handy because they don t mutate the original array. Which is important about react data management. Or even for redux.

Comment: One last thing, how does this work? const {id, repos} = collection. and {id} in the filter method. about this I researched a bit but could not find the answer

Comment: Object destructing. So it takes id and repos of collection object.

Comment: Same as const id = collection.id, repos = collection.repos

Comment: I understood when I searched. The only one that does not make sense is {id} in filter. Since you're not doing something like const {id} = repos;

I looked quickly at the article and did not find out about it.